# Open a SBET file format in GIS software

Tags: convert, import, lidar, trajectory, sbet

After a LiDAR flight, we can get a file containing the airplane trajectory in SBET format - Smoothed Best Estimate of Trajectory.

Is it possible to open it in a GIS software like QGIS or ArcGIS?

If not, is there a way to convert it into a readable file?

Comment: If you are open to using python, I was able to use [this python script](http://arsf-dan.nerc.ac.uk/trac/attachment/wiki/Processing/SyntheticDataset/sbet_handler.py) with a little modification to read SBET/SOL files.  I created an ArcGIS python tool and added the option to convert the SBET positions to 3D point at a user defined interval (i.e. 1 second).

Comment: @Barbarossa The Python script you have linked to has been moved and is now available from https://github.com/pmlrsg/arsf_tools (read_nav_file.py).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PDAL](http://pdal.io) has an [SBET reader](http://www.pdal.io/stages/readers.sbet.html) (and a writer too) that you could use to convert the file into text and then on to most other formats.

```
pdal translate myfile.sbet output.txt
```

When working with Lat/Lon default precision is not enough, so use:

```
pdal translate myfile.sbet output.txt -w writers.text --writers.text.precision=5
```

It is a very simple format. See the [PDAL source code](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/blob/master/io/SbetReader.cpp) for more detail on what's in there.

Comment: Great @Howard Butler! As far as I saw, the PDAL is available to windows via http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ (just for 64bit version). Thanks.

Comment: The default precision for the translate command is not enough when working with Lat/Lon. I would use pdal translate mysbet.sbet mytext.txt -w writers.text --writers.text.precision=5

Comment: Also, pdal is now available with the Anaconda package.