# Identifying SBET coordinate system and reprojecting it with PDAL?

Tags: coordinate-system, csv, lidar, pdal, sbet

I've received discrete return LiDAR data from a data provider, which was acquired with an [Optech C-300 scanner](http://www.teledyneoptech.com/index.php/product/orion-altm/). In addition to the LAS data, the delivery includes the trajectory information in the Applanix SBET (Smoothed Best Estimate of Trajectory) binary format.

I was hoping to visualise the SBET data in QGIS - so I used [PDAL](https://www.pdal.io/stages/readers.sbet.html) SBET Reader to convert the file to ASCII as follows:

```
pdal translate input.sbet output.csv
```

The output file includes X, Y, Z coordinates, however these don't relate to my local projection (EPSG:2157):

```
"GpsTime" "Y" "X" "Z"
556975.005 0.933 -0.159 931.402
556975.010 0.933 -0.159 931.362
556975.015 0.933 -0.159 931.362
556975.020 0.933 -0.159 931.362
556975.025 0.933 -0.159 931.362
556975.030 0.933 -0.159 931.362
556975.035 0.933 -0.159 931.361
```

The min_x, min_y is (-0.1690, 0.9110) and the max_x, max_y is (-0.1650, 0.9130).

Using the SBET file, is it possible to identify which projection the X and Y coordinates relate to? And if so, can PDAL reproject these coordinates to EPSG:2157? Or is it something that needs to be corrected by the data provider?

Comment: From what kind of platform and instrument were these data collected? SBET is usually used to store trajectory information, e.g. from an integrated GNSS/IMU unit.

Comment: From an Optech C-300 LiDAR scanner.

Comment: thanks for your comments and suggestions - I've attempted to update the question further with more details and specifications.

Comment: @dmci assuming the data is from Irland, can you add the extent (min/max) of the X, Y and Z coordinates in your file? The sample seems to be all at the same spot.

Comment: I wrote the SBET reader, and it doesn't have much real world usage. Can you open an issue in https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL (cc-ing @gadomski) and possibly provide a link to some sample data? That will allow me to take a look and make sure the problem is/isn't PDAL's fault :-). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks all. @AndreJ - I've updated the question to include the min/max coordinates from the SBET file.

Comment: @gadomski - I've opened an issue on the PDAL github and shared a download link to the SBET file in question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the provided download link stops at 5.1 MB. The extent of lat and lon does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

The follow up discussion from this question can be found in [github.com/PDAL, issue 1524](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/1524#issuecomment-286413228).

As commented by @abellgithub (mar/17), SBET files do not carry a Coordinate Reference System (CRS) information.

The alternative suggested was to ask the data providers which CRS was used, and then, reproject the SBET file to EPSG:2157.

```
pdal translate -f filters.reprojection --filters.reprojection.in_srs=<some srs> --filters.reproejction.out_srs="EPSG:2157" input.sbet output.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the data is unprojected latitude longitude (usually WGS84, EPSG:4326), stored in radians. The precision of the SBET translation is therefore a bit low to give useful coordinates.

0.933 times 180° divided by PI --> 53.457°

-0.159 times 180° divided by PI --> -9.110°

Comment: use `--writers.text.precision=n` parameter to correct for Lat/Long. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/175041/108